# simple ctor dilema - inheritance

Tags: c++, constructor

What is the outcome of the following code, and please describe why :)

```
class Mother
{
  public:
    Mother ( ) {
        cout << "r" << endl;
    }
    ~Mother ( )
    {
        cout << "n" << endl;
    }
};
class Daughter: public Mother
{
  public:
    Daughter ( )
    {
        cout << "a" << endl;
    }
    ~Daughter ( )
    {
        cout << "b" << endl;
    }
};
void foo(Mother m){ cout<< "foo" <<endl;}
int main( )
{
    Daughter lea;
    Mother* Rachel;
    foo(lea);
}
```

I am not sure why, but someone told me it will be:
r,a,foo,n,b,n (from left to right)

Why calling "Daughter lea" generates r and a? due to inheritance?
And why did "foo" suddenly appear? shouldn't it be last?
Thanks!

Comment: Why not run it and find out?  With a debugger you can even step through the code and see what is happening while it is running.

Comment: @ArielNitzan add that in the main question else u will get more downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the flow of your program execution

```
int main( )
{
    Daughter lea;   // <- invokes the ctor of Daughter, but after Mother
    Mother* Rachel; // Nothing happens --pointer
    foo(lea);       // foo->~Mother, ~Mother called upon exit
}                   // ~Daughter->~Mother
```

So, First, when creating `lea`, It calls ctor of `Daughter`. As this is derived from `Mother`, `Mother` ctor get called first followed by `Daughter`, **Order of ctor calls in C++ is `base->derived`**

Second line does not do anything as it is pointer declaration.

Now, Here is the fun part, When we call `foo()` with `lea`, It gets converted to `Mother` and passed to foo. Upon exit from `foo`, `~Mother` is called due to local scope of `Mother` in foo.

When the program exits, It destructs the `lea`, which is of type `Daughter`. The order of destruction is opposite to order of construction. i.e **derieved ->base, Hence ~Daughter followed by ~Mother.**

That's why you are getting

```
r
a
foo
n
b
n
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output as expected is :-

```
r
a
foo
n
b
n
```

As `Daughter` is derived from `Mother`, hence when you create an object of `Daughter` first the constructor of `Mother` ie `the base class` will be called & then that of `Daughter` ie `the derived class`. Hence you get `r` & `a` first.

`foo` comes next because you are calling the function `foo` (that you must be understanding). The `n` that follows `foo` is due to the destructor of `m` in the function `foo`.

Lastly as `lea` is destroyed, the destructor of `Daughter` is called first followed by that of `Mother`. This is because destructors release resources in the opposite way of which they were created. Hence you get `b` then `n` again.